# How do I get all fields of embedded classes?

Tags: java, reflection

I have an instance of class Account (let's call it entity):

```
private String accountType;
private List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
private Date createdDate;
private ContactInfo contactInfo;
private AccountStatus accountStatus;
```

As you can see there are classes "ContactInfo" and "AccountStatus" inside. How can I get all fields in Account class and all it's used classes providing that I have the entity?

This is what I write now, which only return all the fields in given entity.

```
private static <T> List<Field> getFields(T entity) {
  List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
  Class clazz = entity.getClass();
  PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors;
  try {
    propertyDescriptors = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors();
  } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
    // do something
  }
  for (PropertyDescriptor pd : propertyDescriptors) {
    Field field = null;
    Class klass = clazz;
    while (klass != null && field == null) {
      try {
        field = klass.getDeclaredField(pd.getName());
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        klass = klass.getSuperclass();
      }
    }
    fields.add(field);
  }
  return fields;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify. You want the types of all its (`Account`'s) fields?

Comment: _As you can see there are classes "ContactInfo" and "AccountStatus" inside_ implies that those classes are declared inside `Account`. That doesn't seem to be the case. You just want the types of the fields declared in `Account`. Which entity are you referring to though?

Comment: I already know how to get fields in Account class, how do I get fields of "ContactInfo" and "AccountStatus" too?

Comment: Ok, so you know how to get the fields of a type. Do you know how to get the `Field`'s type? What you really want is to recursively get all fields declared in `Account` and in the fields declared inside the types of those fields, and so on? What if the type is an interface type?

Comment: @RogerChien If you know how to get fields of `Account`, what prevents you from doing the exact same thing to `ContactInfo`?

Comment: @Andreas as you can see in my `getFields(T entity)` method, it's a generic method, which I don't know what's inside the entity.

Comment: @RogerChien *Why* is it generic? The only use of `T` is the declaration of the `entity` parameter, and the only use of that is the `getClass()` call, and it doesn't care what the type of `entity` is, especially when you assign the result to a *raw(!)* `Class` variable, so you might as well remove `<T>` and just say `getFieldsThatHaveSetter(Object entity)`.

Comment: If you then change to `getFieldsThatHaveSetter(Object entity) { getFieldsThatHaveSetter(entity.getClass()) }` and then have `getFieldsThatHaveSetter(Class clazz)` with all that code, you can then call it recursively with `getFieldsThatHaveSetter(pd.getPropertyType())`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Andreas new I have it solved:

```
private static <T extends BaseEntity> List<Field> getFields(T entity) {
  List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
  Class clazz = entity.getClass();
  PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors;
  try {
    propertyDescriptors = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors();
  } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
    return fields;
  }
  for (PropertyDescriptor pd : propertyDescriptors) {
    List<Field> subFields = getSettableFields(pd.getPropertyType());
    if (subFields.isEmpty()) {
      try {
        fields.add(clazz.getDeclaredField(pd.getName()));
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return fields;
      }
    } else {
      fields.addAll(subFields);
    }
  }
  return fields;
}
private static List<Field> getFields(Class<?> clazz) {
  List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
  PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors;
  try {
    propertyDescriptors = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors();
  } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
    return fields;
  }
  for (PropertyDescriptor pd : propertyDescriptors) {
    try {
      fields.add(clazz.getDeclaredField(pd.getName()));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      return fields;
    }
  }
  return fields;
}
```